# Calculating grand total difference between months

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, case-when

I have 3 tables added below as a sample. I want to get variations of the grand totals between consecutive months (i.e. the grand_total difference between Jan and Feb).

The query below gives me the attached result but I have to add a new line of code for each upcoming month. Besides that, it creates a new column for each grand total variation.

opps_id_c: refers to opps_id  in opportunities table
contract_id_c: refers to contract_id in contract table

How can I optimize the query?
Any helps would be appreciated!

**Table: Invoice**

```
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| issued_date | invoice_id | opps_id_c | contract_id_c |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 1/31/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 3/31/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 3/31/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 1/31/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 4/30/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 5/31/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 6/30/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 6/30/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 2/28/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
| 2/28/2019   |       6235 |      1235 |          2211 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

**Table: Opportunities**

```
+---------+-------------+
| opps_id | grand_total |
+---------+-------------+
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
|    1235 |         460 |
+---------+-------------+
```

**Table: Contract**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| contract_id | grand_total |
+-------------+-------------+
|        2211 |         396 |
|        2211 |         396 |
|        2211 |         396 |
|        2211 |         460 |
|        2211 |         460 |
|        2211 |         396 |
|        2211 |         460 |
|        2211 |         169 |
|        2211 |         396 |
|        2211 |         169 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT
      SUM(t3.var_jan_feb) AS var_jan_feb,
      SUM(t3.var_feb_mar) AS var_feb_mar,
      SUM(t3.var_mar_apr) AS var_mar_apr,
      SUM(t3.var_apr_may) AS var_apr_may,
      SUM(t3.var_may_jun) AS var_may_jun,
      SUM(t3.var_jun_jul) AS var_jun_jul,
      SUM(t3.var_jul_aug) AS var_jul_aug,
      SUM(t3.var_aug_sept) AS var_aug_sept,
      SUM(t3.var_sept_oct) AS var_sept_oct,
      SUM(t3.var_oct_nov) AS var_oct_nov    
FROM    
(SELECT
    t2.opps_id_c,
    SUM(contract_jan) AS contract_jan,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_jan) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_feb) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_feb) - SUM(contract_jan)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_jan_feb,
    SUM(contract_feb) AS contract_feb,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_feb) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_mar) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_mar) - SUM(contract_feb)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_feb_mar,
    SUM(contract_mar) AS contract_mar,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_mar) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_apr) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_apr) - SUM(contract_mar)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_mar_apr,
    SUM(contract_apr) AS contract_apr,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_apr) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_may) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_may) - SUM(contract_apr)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_apr_may,
    SUM(contract_may) AS contract_may,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_may) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_june) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_june) - SUM(contract_may)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_may_jun,
    SUM(contract_june) AS contract_june,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_june) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_july) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_july) - SUM(contract_june)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_jun_jul,
    SUM(contract_july) AS contract_july,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_july) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_aug) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_aug) - SUM(contract_july)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_jul_aug,
    SUM(contract_aug) AS contract_aug,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_aug) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_sept) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_sept) - SUM(contract_aug)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_aug_sept,
    SUM(contract_sept) AS contract_sept,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_sept) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_oct) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_oct) - SUM(contract_sept)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_sept_oct,
    SUM(contract_oct) AS contract_oct,
    CASE WHEN SUM(contract_oct) <> 0 AND SUM(contract_nov2019) <> 0 THEN SUM(contract_nov) - SUM(contract_oct)
    ELSE 0 END AS var_oct_nov,
    SUM(contract_nov) AS contract_nov        
FROM    
(SELECT  -- grand total contract per month for each opps
    t1.opps_id_c,
    t1.issued_date,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-01-31' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_jan,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-02-28' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_feb,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-03-31' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_mar,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-04-30' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_apr,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-05-31' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_may,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-06-30' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_june,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-07-31' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_july,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-08-31' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_aug,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-09-30' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_sept,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-10-31' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_oct,
    CASE WHEN t1.issued_date = '2019-11-30' THEN t1.contract_grand_total ELSE 0 END AS contract_nov            
FROM    
(SELECT
    i.invoice_id,
    i.amount,
    i.opps_id_c,
    o.grand_total AS opps_grand_total,
    i.issued_date,
    i.contract_id_c,
    c.grand_total AS contract_grand_total
FROM
    db.invoice i
LEFT JOIN db.opps o ON
    i.opps_id_c = o.opps_id
LEFT JOIN db.contract c ON
    i.contract_id_c = c.contract_id
) AS t1) AS t2    
WHERE 
    (contract_nov > 0
    OR contract_dec > 0
    OR contract_jan > 0
    OR contract_feb > 0
    OR contract_mar > 0
    OR contract_apr > 0
    OR contract_may > 0
    OR contract_june > 0
    OR contract_july > 0
    OR contract_aug > 0
    OR contract_sept > 0
    OR contract_oct > 0
    OR contract_nov2019 > 0)
GROUP BY
    t2.opps_id_c) AS t3
```

**Result of the query:**
[image]

Comment: It would be much more useful if you could minimize your sample and take some more readable data.

Comment: @S-Man I minimized to 10 records and added a description for two column names. Please let me know if it is okay.

Comment: Great would be to take integer values instead of doubles because one can check much easier if the result is ok. Second: Please change your random looking ids into something easier as A - Z. This would help a lot, because currently it's hard to see which records should fit. Finally the expected output would be very nice.

Comment: Much more easy is to use postgres analytical functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @S-Man Since one id has different grand totals in contracts over time, to simplify I modified the tables for only one opps_id. Hope should be fine!

Comment: @ecp How to do that? Can you add your solution if you know?

Comment: I posted the main idea, just adapt it, shoud be fine.

Comment: @KadirŞenkaya did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT issued_date,zeroifnull(total-lag(total) OVER (PARTITION BY issued_date ASC)) var
FROM (
    SELECT issued_date, sum(o.grand_total+c.grand_total) total
    FROM Invoice i
    LEFT JOIN Opportunities o
    ON i.opps_id_c=o.opps_id
    LEFT JOIN Contract c
    ON i.contract_id_c=c.contract_id
    GROUP BY 1
 ) t
```